# Why is this sum of products of the reciprocals of the natural numbers up to n equal to e - 1

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Ok that's a mouthful, so using notation will be clearer easier. I wrote a quick script to approximate
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \prod_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}= 1.7182818284590455$$ which looks a lot like $e-1$. Is this correct and if so, why? That is, what is a proof of this?

Comment: Just check the power series of $e$. It is very simple.$e^x=1+x+x^2/2!+..+x^n/n!+...$ for the point $x=1$

Comment: Yeah you're right, I should've been able to figure that out!

Comment: You probably mean $\dfrac{1}{k}$, not $\dfrac{1}{n}$...

Answer (score 3):

Interesting!  Well at first glance, $$\prod_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k} = \frac{1}{n!}$$ which shows up in the power series for $e^x$, so if you plug in $1$ in for $x$ in $e^x$ you get the sum you listed plus a "zero" term which is $1$:
$$e^x = 1 + x + \frac{1}{2!}x^2+ \frac{1}{3!}x^3+ \frac{1}{4!}x^2+ \frac{1}{2!}x^4+\cdots$$ so $$e = 1 + 1 + \frac{1}{2!}+\frac{1}{3!}+\frac{1}{4!}+\cdots$$

Answer (score 0):

SInce your sript computed the partial sums
$$S_p=\sum_{n=1}^p \prod_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}$$ you have generated the values of
$$S_p=e\,\frac{ \Gamma (p+1,1)}{\Gamma (p+1)}-1$$ where appears the incomplete gamma function.

The ratio $R_p=\frac{ \Gamma (p+1,1)}{\Gamma (p+1)}$ converges quite fast to $1$. For example
$$R_{10}=0.9999999899522336243090629455394169709086$$
$$R_{20}=0.9999999999999999999924573749227947215240$$
$$R_{30}=0.9999999999999999999999999999999999538195$$